# Dispatch multiple async actions with Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm building an app with Expo/React Native and using Redux via Redux Toolkit to handle the store/state of the app using slices.

I've been using this setup for a while without complications because my functions are simple (like user/auth, cart, category and products reducers).

But for this app I need to load multiple catalogs from a single endpoint. To achieve this I have created a "catalogs" slice with multiple reducers and a single action which performs the requests and dispatches the reducer depending on the name of the catalog.

```
const initialState = {
  catalogOne: [],
  catalogTwo: [],
  catalogThree: [],
  catalogN: []
}

const catalogsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "catalogs",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    catalogOneRequestSucceeded: (state,action) => {
      state.catalogOne = action.payload
    },
    catalogTwoRequestSucceeded: (state,action) => {
      state.catalogTwo = action.payload
    },
    // ... and so on a reducer for each catalog
  }
});
```

And then I have the following action which is used to request the endpoint with the name of the catalog and dispatch the reducer:

```
export const catalogRequest = (catalogName) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const state = getState();

  try {
    const rsp = await axios.get(`https://catalogEndpointBase/${catalogName}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${state.user.accessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    switch (catalogName) {
      case "catalogOne":
        dispatch(catalogOneRequestSucceeded(rsp.data));
        break;
      case "catalogTwo":
        dispatch(catalogTwoRequestSucceeded(rsp.data));
        break;
      case "catalogThree":
        dispatch(catalogThreeRequestSucceeded(rsp.data));
        break;
    }

    return rsp.data;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};
```

So my question now is: how do I dispatch this action multiple times in an "async/await" way so the catalogs are loaded one after the other? and also: am I doing it the right way or is there a better approach to this kind of multiple requests?

I was thinking of something like this, but I don't really know how to accomplish that:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadCatalogsAsync = async() => {
      try {
        await dispatch(catalogRequest("catalogOne"));
        await dispatch(catalogRequest("catalogTwo"));
        await dispatch(catalogRequest("catalogThree"));
        // ... and so on for all my catalogs
      } catch ( e ) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }

    loadCatalogsAsync();
  }, []);
}
```

The goal is to find a best-practice for kind of behavior where the app is required to fetch multiple data when the app is loaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to `await` the `dispatch`. You also don’t need a `try`/`catch` block because the thunk will catch any API errors and dispatch a “rejected” action.  You can just `dispatch` your three thunks.

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(catalogRequest("catalogOne"));
  dispatch(catalogRequest("catalogTwo"));
  dispatch(catalogRequest("catalogThree"));
}, []);
```

---

I would write your thunk and your reducer a lot simpler.  I would use one action type and let the `catalogName` be part of the `payload` (you can also access it from the `meta` property of the action).  You could delete that entire `switch` block in your thunk and the corresponding case reducers.  Instead you can have one case reducer that updates the correct property in the state based on `action.payload.catalogName`.

thunk:

```
export const catalogRequest = createAsyncThunk(
  "catalogs/request",
  async (catalogName, { getState }) => {
    const state = getState();
    const rsp = await axios.get(`https://catalogEndpointBase/${catalogName}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${state.user.accessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    });
    return {
      data: rsp.data,
      catalogName
    };
  }
);
```

slice:

```
const catalogsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "catalogs",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [catalogRequest.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      const { data, catalogName } = action.payload;
      state[catalogName] = data;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This seems like anti pattern, you don't know the order in which state are updated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using Promise.all(). I needed to wait for all initial tasks, which are async actions and not dependent on each other, to be completed before hiding the splash screen (using RNBootSplash):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const runInitialTasks = async () => {
      await Promise.all([dispatch(initGame()), dispatch(initOnboarding())]);
    };
    runInitialTasks().then(() =>
      RNBootSplash.hide({fade: true, duration: 400}),
    );
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```